Como mostrar a que datos pertenecen los resultados de la query en sql?
Tengo un dataset que incluye una columna donde se indica el nombre de la estacion de donde salio cada trayecto, la columna tiene el titulo de "start_station_name". Quiero encontrar cuales son las estaciones de las que salieron mas trayectos
Por el momento tengo lo siguiente:
 SELECT  
Count(start_station_name) AS station_visits

FROM `woven-benefit-418.Cyclis_Analysis.January_stats` 

GROUP BY start_station_name 

Esto me da como resultado una tabla con el numero de trayectos iniciados por estacion, pero solo me da el conteo y no me indica cual es el nombre de la estacion a la que pertenece esa suma:
Fila station_visits
 1         66
 2         88
 3         66
 4         89
 5         97
 6         106
 7         109
 8         203
 9         863
  

Gracias!!

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! y si agregas start_station_name????

Solo tienes que agregar el nombre de la estación a la lista de columnas.
SELECT  start_station_name,
        COUNT(start_station_name) AS station_visits
FROM `woven-benefit-418.Cyclis_Analysis.January_stats` 
GROUP BY start_station_name;

